# "Kyle!" She screamed it as loud as she could, praying inside as she did it

Tags: meaning

> *"Kyle!"* She screamed it as loud as she could, praying inside **as she did it**.

What is the meaning of the bold part of the sentence? And what use does it have for the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

> "Kyle"

The quotation marks indicate that this was spoken.

> She screamed it as loud as she could, ...

This indicates *how* it was spoken.

> ...praying inside as she did it.

This indicates that she was *praying inside* as she *did it*.

*Did it*, in this case, refers to her screaming [it as loud as she could].

Interestingly, it would still mean the same thing even if it said:

> praying inside as she did

All in all, the sentence means:

She screamed "Kyle" as loud as she was able to, and at the same time as that, she prayed inside.

Comment: It's probably easier to understand to say that that *did* refers back to *screamed*. (In my opinion, it's a little better, since it's more obvious and straightforward, than saying *it* refers to *screaming*.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Hmm. Interesting. It would still mean the same thing without "it", right?

Comment: Yes, that's how I parsed it: [did it] = [screamed it].

Comment: @jimsug Does it add anything to the sentence?

Comment: @Man_From_India Not really, I don't think. It might be emphatic, but I doubt that. You could also say _as she did so_, with the same effect.